# Problem with Proposition 1 of Google Deepmind's 'Weight uncertainty in Neural Networks'

Tags: neural-networks, bayesian-networks, expectation

I'm going through the paper [*Weight Uncertainty in Neural Networks*](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1505.05424.pdf) by Google Deepmind. In the final line of the proof of proposition 1, the integral and the derivative are swapped. Then the derivative is taken. But this somehow yields 2 derivatives of $f$ with respect to $\theta$. I thought that this was the result of a product rule applied to $q(\epsilon)$ and $f(w,\theta)$ and then the chain rule. But that does not yield the same outcome as $\frac{\partial q(\epsilon)}{\partial \theta} = 0 $. My question is: does anyone understand how the equation in the last line comes about?

[image: Proposition 1]

Answer (score 2):

we start with

$\frac{\partial}{\partial \theta} \mathbb E_{q(\mathbf w\mid\theta)}[f(\mathbf w, \theta)]$

using definition of expectation for continuous case:

$\mathbb E[X] = \int xp(x) dx$

for the first equation we get:

$\frac{\partial}{\partial \theta} \int f(\mathbf w, \theta)q(\mathbf w \mid \theta) d\mathbf w$

we swap $q(\mathbf w \mid \theta) d\mathbf w$ for $q(\epsilon)d\epsilon$ and we get:

$\frac{\partial}{\partial \theta} \int f(\mathbf w, \theta)q(\epsilon)d\epsilon$

using definition of expectation again we have:

$\frac{\partial}{\partial \theta} \mathbb E_{q(\epsilon)}[f(\mathbf w,\theta)]$

i believe dominant convergence theorem let's us interchange expectation and derivative and we have:

$\mathbb E_{q(\epsilon)}[\frac{\partial}{\partial \theta}f(\mathbf w,\theta)]$

we have a function $f$ that depends on two variables $\mathbf w$ and $\theta$. In order to get a full derivative of such function we need to take derivative of $f$ with respect to both variables. We have:

$\mathbb E_{q(\epsilon)}[\frac{\partial f(\mathbf w,\theta)}{\partial \theta} + \frac{\partial f(\mathbf w,\theta)}{\partial \mathbf w} \frac{\partial \mathbf w}{\partial \theta}]$

First term inside expectation is derivative of function $f$ with respect to $\theta$ directly, and in the second term $f$ is derivated with respect to $\mathbf w$, but we need to apply chain rule to get full derivative with respect to $\theta$

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This solves it. I stared at this for a while but did not take into account that $\textbf{w}$ is a function of $\theta$.